# What's the best method to alert a user of an upcoming video conference?

Tags: notification, alerts

We are going to develop an app that allows a video conference to be scheduled. Person 1 will schedule a time based on the availability of Person 2.

What I'd like to happen is when Person 1 opens the application on the scheduled date, the first screen would show that s/he has an upcoming conference call very soon (with a countdown timer) and when the countdown timer ends, it will show something like "Start Conference Now", which, when the user clicks, will start connecting Person 1 to Person 2.

Let's say Person 1 scheduled an appointment next Tuesday at 10AM. What is the best way to alert this person that s/he should open the application at 10AM (or few minutes before that)? Should it be an SMS? A Push Notification?

Comment: Some good information here - http://uxthing.blogspot.in/2016/05/mobile-app-notifications-for-business.html and here https://uxplanet.org/how-to-craft-mobile-notifications-that-users-actually-want-7b585e0e1fa1#.z10m759mk

Comment: Websites are really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be all.

Suppose when tuesday starts, app must send a SMS saying "You have a conference meeting today, present before 15 minutes."

When conference about to start send him a Push Notification saying, "Conference will start in 15 minutes, Open XYZ App or click here to open."

OR when Person 1 schedule a meeting, Person 2 should allow to Download a message to Save the dates and time to Calender so that he could get a Reminder.

Its totally up to you, there are possibilies of getting a system generated Calls too.